# Keycloak cannot get RPT with Permissions using service account token

Tags: java, keycloak

I am using Keycloak: 4.8.3.Final

I have the following clients in Keycloak

- **UserService**
- **InventoryService**

**InventoryService** has some resources defined in Keycloak and Authorization enabled.

**UserService** (as a service-account) has the necessary client-roles assigned  in the **service-account-roles** tab

Whenever someone tries to access the APIs of InventoryService, I do the following:

- Get the access token from the Authorization Header
- get RPT (as mentioned [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/5.0/authorization_services/#obtaining-user-entitlements))
- introspect the RPT if the desired permissions are present or not.

I am getting the following error response when the UserService tries to access the apis of InventoryService

```
{
  "error": "invalid_resource",
  "error_description": "Resource with id [item] does not exist."
}
```

Here is the code snippet in java.

I am getting the following error response when the UserService tries to access the apis of InventoryService

```
AuthorizationResource authResource = authzClient.authorization(at);
AuthorizationRequest request = new AuthorizationRequest();
request.addPermission(resourceId, scopes);
AuthorizationResponse authResponse = authResource.authorize(request);
String rpt = authResponse.getToken();
```

When I remove the line 
**request.addPermission(resourceId, scopes);** 
I am able to get an RPT with all the list of Permissions. but if I include it the above error is thrown.

Btw, one more observation is: the above code snippet works fine when the token belongs to a User (not a service account).

Can any let me know what is happening? Is this a bug in Keycloak?

Comment: did you try to add the actual resource id of the resource you are trying to ask permissions for?

Answer (score 0):

This problem persists in KeyCloak 11.0.2. Service accounts are [explicitly excluded](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authorization/authorization/AuthorizationTokenService.java#L590) in the authorization token service.

However, you can work around this by setting the `azp` claim to something other than your `client_id` via a protocol mapper on your client.

[image: protocol mapper on your client].